# restrict size of world three.js and orbitcontrols.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, geometry, controls

I have created a plane geometry within the world and I have looked into the orbit controls library and I have restricted some controls with `controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;` and `controls.enableRotate = false;` which is all good. However, I can't see to find an option to restrict panning as I want the pan to stop at the parameters of the plane geometry so it stays within the plane if that makes sense. Because if I continue to pan it goes on forever. I have tried `maxDistance` and `minDistance`, but to no avail. Maybe I need to clamp the camera position between certain values?..but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: This question was already answered here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-limit-pan-in-orbitcontrols-for-orthographiccamera/9061/2

Comment: @Mugen87 Thank you so much. It worked. However, I am trying also to change the parameters depending on the zoom level so it always fits the plane. I have tried incorporating this in orbitcontrols `if (this.maxDistance = 900 ) {
     scope.target.clamp( minPan, maxPan );
     
    } else if (this.minDistance = 400){
     scope.target.clamp(minPanStart,maxPanStart);
    }`   I created separate values for `minPanStart` and `maxPanStart` But it doesn't work, is it even possible to change it like this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that. Could be a a good separate question (here at stackoverflow or at the forum).